# Python - Readline Control-D after non-empty line does not work why?

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I am sorry if what I am asking seems odd. I want to loop over each line on standard input and return a modified line to standard output immediately. I have code that works, mostly. However I do not know how to make this work completely.

I have the following code

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()

    if not line:
        break

    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

When being used interactively this will exit if there is an EOF on a new line, however if there is text before I type Control-D I must give the code twice before it will exit the line, and then once more before the loop will exit.

How do I fix this.

Comment: you have to test the content of `line` for a potential EOF

Comment: Did you actually run your code? I think you should get an error at `while true:`.

Comment: Yes I ran my code. I am not that whiny.

Comment: Njzk2 how do I test for the EOF?  Also I do not break out of the readline until 2 control-Ds how do I work around this.

Comment: And you didn't get a `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`? How is this possible ... ?

Comment: I mistyped here True as true. As I could not copy and paste. As my code was on a terminal that does not have the internet where I presently am.

Answer (score 3):

I think my answer from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/weird-control-d-behavior/19097#19097) can be copied immediately:

> It has to do with `^D` really does: it just stops the current
>   `read(2)` call.
>
> If the program does `int rdbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);`
>   and you press `^D` inbetween, `read()` returns with the currently read
>   bytes in the buffer, returning their number. The same happens on line
>   termination; the `\n` at the end is always delivered.
>
> So only a `^D` at the start of a line or after another `^D` has the
>   desired effect of having `read()` return `0`, signalizing EOF.

And this behaviour, of course, affects Python code as well.

Comment: Thankyou. I had not understood this unti I read it about 6 times. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A strategy suggested in the python docs is:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

See the [IO Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: I failed to make this clear, I want the output to be immediate. This waits until the EOF on the input until the output is written.

Comment: this is actually a really interesting question - your code is "right", it's just a question of getting the interactivity to give you the right input